# Tomcat threadpool full, but all RUNNABLE

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, ajp

I have a set of worker threads where I run anonymous class runnables for long-running jobs. These threads last long after the response has been returned, but it seems that the thread that these Runnables were created on are still alive, and considered in use.

For implementation's sake, here is the code... in so many fewer words.

```
@Path("/myawesomeApp")
public class TheThing {
    static final TheWorkerPool pool = new TheWorkerPool();
    static final HashMap<Integer,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String>();
    static int mapIdx = 0;

    @Context
    HttpServletContext context;

    @POST
    Integer doStuff() {
        Integer thisVariable = mapIdx++;     
        pool.enqueue(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                map.put(thisVariable, OtherStuff.dothings());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Every one of them is stuck on the following:

```
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.recvbb(Native Method)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.readt(AjpAprProcessor.java:1049)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.readMessage(AjpAprProcessor.java:1140)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1509)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: how are all the threads stuck in a stack trace which doesn't include any user code?  unless your class is "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker"?

Comment: Also wondering this.  My suspicion is that it is related to a memory leak involving some sort of thread-local stuff (anonymous classes hold a reference to the parent class, my parent class contains a reference to @Context). If this is the case, it wouldn't be hanging in any particular piece of code. An analyzer shows this exists, and I'm working to clear that up with the hopes that this memory is what is holding onto this worker thread. I just don't understand why tomcat would consider the thread blocked because of a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess TheThing's code is never called at all in this case.
See [AjpAprProcessor's source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-coyote/7.0.0/org/apache/coyote/ajp/AjpAprProcessor.java#364). It's stuck on reading some required http request's headers.

So check the ajp configuration and also ensure that client sends http requests correctly.

Try enabling logging on apache side.